# Associating onXXX() calls caused by a single user action

Tags: android

Suppose that I have a RadioGroup in Android.  When I tap a RadioButton, a number of listeners are called, including the button's `OnClickListener.onClick()` method and the group's `OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged()` method.

Is there any way to make an association between those events, to know that they were both triggered by the same tap?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you imported the wrong `OnCheckChangeListener`.

`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener` only includes `onCheckedChanged()`.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

Comment: Yes, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener only has that one method but that's not the question.  The listeners all work.  My question is whether there is a way to know what event caused each of the callbacks to be called, so I can know whether two events were caused by the same tap.

Comment: Okay. In my understanding of your question and of Android's touch events, those callbacks will both get triggered by the same tap, and you cannot be sure or not about that, as those callbacks transports no other data. But I might be wrong.